# What is a logo called when it consists of a symbol, title and slogan?

Tags: logo, terminology

Do logos that are constructed using a symbol, title and slogan have a specific name?

Comment: A slogan is not part of a logo... it is a slogan.

Comment: @Rafael Unless it is part of a logo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I post this second answer using translated Spanish words, my apologies if any of them do not match the reader's usual vocabulary or dictionary. This is how I know the definition of a graphic representation as a company image.*

There are five types:

- Typogram

  - Monogram
  - Acronym
  - Slogan
- Pictogram
- Ideogram
- Mascots
- Heraldry

### Typogram

Graphic representation of a word or set of words, real or not. In graphic design, besides the use of words there are three derivatives: monograms, acronyms, slogan.

> #### Monogram
>
> Graphic representation made with the initials or other letters of the company name
>
> #### Acronym
>
> Word graphic representation made by two or more different ones, using their abbreviations or different parts of each.
>
> #### Slogan
>
> Phrase sometimes used as a corporate image halfway between company brand and advertising

### Pictogram

Graphic representation with direct reference to a specific object

### Ideogram

Graphic representation of abstract configurations.

### Mascots

Characters used to generate a greater approach between the company or its activities and a mass audience. Unlike pictograms, mascots have gestures, changes of position, changing personalities, or different graphic attitudes.

### Heraldry

Uses combinations of two or more objects from those listed above but with a meaning for each component.

---

Obviously each of these elements admit combinations, between them or between each one of them. The answer to this question remains the same, the use of a symbol + word + slogan is a **combination** of two or more of the elements described.

[image]

Comment: Those are actually better and make more sense than the 99designs nonsense. +1

Answer (score 22):

## Combination marks

According to [99designs](https://99designs.es/blog/tips/types-of-logos/) there are seven types of logos*:

[image: types of logos]

- Abstract
- Emblem
- Lettermark
- Mascots
- Pictorial
- Wordmark
- **Combination marks**

> A combination mark is a logo comprised of a combined wordmark or lettermark and a pictorial mark, abstract mark, or mascot.

[image]

The conclusion would be combination mark + slogan.

<sub>*These names usually vary according to the author or study center.</sub>

Comment: I learnt something there.

Comment: Could you put the answer "combination mark + slogan" in bold rather than the not-answer "combination mark" which suggests it's the answer?

Comment: I can't see the difference between "Combination mark" and "Emblem logo".

Comment: Hmm, 'wordmark' and 'lettermark'  aren't English words.  These look like made up terms. The usual word in English for a logo made up from a word/letters is a 'logotype'.   The OED does list "word mark" which is two separate words, however it refers to a real or invented word used as a trademark, not the design of the actual logotype itself.  Also a "letter mark", again two separate words,  is where you have a letter/letters used as a symbol or mark of identification, not necessarily anything to do with logos as such.

Comment: That's why I wrote the last sentence at the answer. We have totally different words in Spanish. Actually, the word logotype has a meaning in origin totally different from a company brand, it is an adaptation. That's why I do not want to use it. Anyway, as you well know, it is very difficult to make everyone happy on this site. It would be fantastic if the answers are seen once and forever as a source of opinions rather than as an absolutism. Everybody wants to rule the world ;-)

Comment: @Masclins In Spanish what on that page is called "emblem", we call it "heraldry" that is much more descriptive. Designates a set of elements each one with a particular meaning.

Comment: @Danielillo - the problem here is quoting 99designs as if they are some kind of authority on design terminology.  Clearly they've invented these terms to somehow help classify the logos on their site. These aren't commonly used in English.  Just another thing to note:  the one called "emblem" would be called a "coat of arms"  here in the UK.

Comment: @BillyKerr You can not imagine the pleasure I would have in answering this question with the terminology translated from Spanish. I don't do it for the avalanche of downvotes, angry comments, flags, etc, etc, etc. If I put the 99designs it's because I found a site with translations more or less adaptable to what I know, but I also think it's not the perfect one.

Comment: What is the difference between a lettermark and a wordmark? Also, what they have as "emblem", I think is commonly referred to as a "seal".

Answer (score 0):

There are many divisions of logos into various types and classes.

The most simple is: Pictographs, Wordmarks, and Ideographs (and combinations thereof).

Pictographs use simplified pictures 
Wordmarks use linguistic elements (either initials or entire words) 
Ideograms are abstract geometric forms

I personally like the addition of one other kind that is rare: Gesturegraphs. Gesturegraphs are some marking, like a brush mark or fingerprint, that is not really a picture or a wordmark, but shows some kind of physical contact. The old Lucents logo was a great example of a pure gesture.